# Unable to pass selected checkboxes ids to controller method using ajax

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to send a list of ids of checkboxes selected every time the user clicks on a checkbox. This will be used for search results to be filtered by categories. I don’t know if this is the correct way to do it but this is what I have tried so far.

This is my partial view with ajax call:

```
@using GAPT.Models
@model ViewModelLookUp

<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#selectedcategories").click(function () {
            var array = [];
            if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                array.push($(this).val());
            }
            else {
                array.pop($(this).val());
            }
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("SearchTours", "Home")',
                dataType: "html",
                traditional: true,
                data: { values: array },
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#selectedcategories').html(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>

@using (Html.BeginForm("SearchCategories", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    foreach (var category in Model.categories)
    {
        <div class="checkbox" id="@{@category.Id}">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="selectedcategories" name="selectedcategories" value="@{@category.Id}"/>@category.Name
            </label>
        </div>
    }
}
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

And this is my controller method that I am trying to reach:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SearchTours(FormCollection collection)
{
    // insert query here

    ViewData["CategAttrTours"] = CategAttrTours;
    return View(CategAttrTours);
}
```

The method in the controller is not being reached and I am getting this error:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHwrW.jpg)

Do you have any idea why I keep getting this error? Is it because I am passing the data incorrectly?
I would appreciate any help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Because your controller method is throwing an exception. You need to debug your code.

Comment: I have a break point in the controller and it is not being reached

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the `contentType` option and stringify your data

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '@Url.Action("SearchTours", "Home")',
    dataType: "html",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", //add this
    data: JSON.stringify({ values: array }), // modify this
    data: { values: array },
    success: function (data) {
                $('#selectedcategories').html(data);
    }
});
```

and change you method to (assumes `category.Id` is typeof `int`)

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SearchTours(IEnumerable<int> values)
```

although your script to generate the array is unnecessary and you can just use

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '@Url.Action("SearchTours", "Home")',
    dataType: "html",
    data: $('form').serialize(),
    success: function (data) {
        $('#selectedcategories').html(data);
    }
});
```

or more simply

```
$.post('@Url.Action("SearchTours", "Home")', $('form').serialize(), function(data) {
    $('#selectedcategories').html(data);
});
```

and change the method to

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SearchTours(IEnumerable<int> selectedcategories)
```

Side note: You should never need to use `FormCollection` in MVC

Comment: Have tried this and it works :) however it only worked for one checkbox...it then gave me the same internal server error or else nothing happens. Do you have any idea why this happens? Thanks a lot.

Comment: If the value of `array` is (say) `[1, 4, 6]` then the value of the parameter in your method will be a collection of `int` containing 1, 4, and 6. I don't know what you mean by only one checkbox. And the `else { array.pop($(this).val()); }` is a bit pointless. But you should be just serializing the form anyway

Comment: Also remove `id="selectedcategories"` from your checkbox. Duplicate `id` attributes are invalid html. Use a class name instead.

Comment: OK, I see what your doing now. You actually making an ajax call every time you check or uncheck a checkbox, and since you initialize a new array each time, it can only ever contain one value (or none if you unchecked an item).

Comment: You need a button (say) `<button type="button" id="save">Save</button>` and then `$('#save').click(function() { ... your ajax call ... });` to that you save all ID's of the checked checkboxes

Comment: Ok will try your last suggestion. Thanks a lot

Comment: It is working fine now I have changed from id to class="selectedcategories" for the checkboxes as you suggested and it is working. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score -1):

remove this

```
dataType: "html"
traditional: true
```

on controller method parameter change this

```
(FormCollection collection)
```

to

```
List<string> values
```

place a break point on the controller and check the values

Comment: I have done the changes you suggested but still no luck. I do have a breakpoint in my controller method but it is not being reached :/